# Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

**Error in Log:** pastebin.com/YLvmkAd4

**FragmentSettings.class:**

```
package com.android.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.ListPreference;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentSettings extends PreferenceFragment {

    [..]

    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
            mListPreference = (ListPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("preference_key");
    
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
        }
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ListView
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            </ListView>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"-->
    <com.android.app.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/scrimInsetsFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:insetForeground="#4000"
        android:elevation="10dp">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
            android:name="com.android.app.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
    </com.android.app.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Devices:**

```
Oppo N1, Android 4.2.2
Samsung Galaxy Note 1, Android 5.1.1
```

*I've spent now hours and hours for this error and couldn't find it. The clue is that exactly the same app is working perfectly on Android 5.1.1.*

## Additional:

**MainActivity.java** pastebin.com/a2NZLZFm

**NavigationDrawerFragment.java** pastebin.com/PqTMiPp3

**fragment_navigation_drawer.xml** pastebin.com/eVeAdv17

Comment: What version of Android did it crash on?

Comment: I've added my used devices. Sorry, forgot that.

Comment: Well, it looks like there is a problem with your fragment.  Did you define an id of fragment_drawer somewhere else maybe?  I don't think it would be the app:layout part...

Comment: Thanks ok. I added all occurrences of "fragment_drawer".

Comment: where is your navigation drawer layout

Comment: @Elltz Now on pastbin.com ^^

Comment: my answer will solve your problem Sir

Comment: lastly pleas post your `R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer,` and let give it a final go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you all helped me a lot, but I fixed it by myself ;)

**I changed..**

```
public class FragmentSettings extends PreferenceFragment {

    public ListPreference mListPreference;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mListPreference = (ListPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("preference_key");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    }
}
```

**To..**

```
public class FragmentSettings extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }

}
```

And removed with this `onCreateView` and `mListPreference` :) Hope this help others ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
<fragment
     android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
     android:name="com.android.app.NavigationDrawerFragment"
     android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
```

use this rather, and inflate the layout in your `onCreateView()` android will take care of adding it ViewGroup/window etc etc

it is this line in your MainActivity

```
 // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_drawer, 
             (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer), mToolbar);
```

remove it and the error will go. Now the next thing is you let the Activity handle the `Drawerlayout` himself. so transfer all drawer codes to your activity and forget the setup() method in your fragment

The reason is since you declared the fragment as embeded in the `Activity`, android initiates it for you, so you do not need to set it up

hope it works

Comment: I'm new to android and not familiar to "inflate", but learning. :) So please go in detail.

Comment: sorry SIr, what i mean is just replace this fragment element in your xml by removing the app:layout you get me? you have already inflated it in your oncreatview of your navi fragment, go to the fragment you will in inflater.inflate so all you need to do is just copy this in replace of yours [more on inflate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) @8m47x

Comment: Yeah that was the easiest part so far :D What needs to be changed here: `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);`?

Comment: nothing needs to be changed sir, its good, maybe you might want to change the last parameter to true.. i guess your problems are gone or?@8m47x

Comment: Nope.. Nothing changed :/

Comment: wait your problem still persists? what is the error this time@8m47x

Comment: sir lets chat [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77204/extended-help) @8m47x

Comment: Sorry: "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq."

Comment: I just upvoted a few of your questions.. You should have the rep needed. :)  (you might nave to give it two tries the first time around...  I had to.)

Comment: I saw that. Thank you! But I'm still now able to access his chat. Error message is the same.

Comment: @8m47x sir, why do you have this ` <ListView
                android:id="@android:id/list"` do you have it on purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line into your styles.xml file.

`<item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>`